# Hitting ctrl+c doesn't stop NPM

Tags: macos, npm, terminal, gulp

When I set up my Gulpfile to watch, it does what I want it to do, but I am not able to quit NPM and for example commit to GitHub. I hit ctrl+c, but it ends up typing a "c" instead of stopping NPM. It used to work, but suddenly I am no longer able stop NPM. I am using iTerm on a Mac if that has anything to do with the issue.

EDIT:
It doesn't work in the default Mac terminal either.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you use "cmd" (apple key) instead of ctrl in macos?

Comment: I've always used ctrl+c to stop NPM in the past. cmd+c is the equivalent to ctrl+c on Windows+Linux.

Comment: And ctrl+c is what is used to stop terminal apps in linux. Well I don't know what your issue is, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working again. Seems like it was the ctrl key itself that had an issue instead of the terminal/NPM.

Answer (score 1):

Typically if you send the interrupt signal via `ctrl + c` it puts `^C` in the terminal. Perhaps your keys are not mapped properly. You can also send a quit signal via `ctrl + \`.

Comment: None of your suggestions unfortunately work. Ctrl in iTerm keymapping menu seems to be mapped to ctrl just like it should.

Comment: It seems that the ctrl button itself is malfunctioning. The Mac keyboard viewer doesn't see that I press the button.